# After switching from gpu to cpu in tensorflow with tf.device("/cpu:0") GPU undocks everytime tf is imported

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu, nvidia

I am using Windows 7. After i tested my GPU in tensorflow, which was awkwardly slowly on a already tested model on cpu, i switched to cpu with:

```
tf.device("/cpu:0")
```

I was assuming that i can switch back to gpu with:

```
tf.device("/gpu:0")
```

However i got the following error message from windows, when i try to rerun with this configuration:

> The device "NVIDIA Quadro M2000M" is not exchange device and can not be removed.

With "nvida-smi" i looked for my GPU, but the system said the GPU is not there.

I restarted my laptop, tested if the GPU is there with "nvida-smi" and the GPU was recogniced.

I imported tensorflow again and started my model again, however the same error message pops up and my GPU vanished.

Is there something wrong with the configuration in one of the tensorflow configuration files? Or Keras files? What can i change to get this work again? Do you know why the GPU is so much slower that the 8 CPUs?

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Reinstalling tensorflow-gpu worked for me.

However there is still the question why that happened and how i can switch between gpu and cpu? I dont want to use a second virtual enviroment.